# How to parameterize a link object/element in QTP?

Tags: automated-tests, qtp

Please give me a hint how to parameterize a link element in QTP...As we can parameterize 'WebEdit' element/object ,can we parameterize 'Link' element/object and how can we?

Answer (score 0):

By parameterizing, do you mean Parameterizing the properties of the Link element to identify it using Descriptive Programming? Or is it something else?? Please elaborate!!
You can build a function like the one below for each object type that you want to use.

```
public Function CreateLinkDescription(LinkInnerTextValue, LinkHrefValue)
    Set objLink = Description.Create()  
    objLink("innertext").Value = LinkInnerTextValue
    objLink("href").Value = LinkHrefValue      
    'Add any other properties that you want to specify in the same fashion as above                                                                                                    
    Set CreateLinkDescription = objLink
End Function
```

Comment: Yes,I mean Parameterizing the properties of the Link element to identify it using Descriptive Programming Or something else!!! I am doing recored and play and want to parameterize through keyword view and data table!

Comment: Did the above code help?? Or are you looking for something else?